# Visual studio 2012- using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I tried to change background  from a javascript function. the color change but immediately return to its original color .
What did I made wrong?
thanks

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function acheck() {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

        }
    </script> </head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><p id="p2" >
        <script>  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        </script>

         </p>

     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="acheck()" Text="Button" />


    </div>

    </form> </body> </html>
```

Comment: You have missed a closing bracket } on your acheck function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you
I found a simple solution:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="acheck();return false;" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to prevent default behavior - it will be posting the form and reloading the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function acheck(e) 
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        e.preventDefault();
    } // this bracket also missing in your code
</script>
```

Other options are:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
```

all with different purposes and outcomes.

Documentation at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML and script?

Comment: this is all the code. I tried a minimal file to found the error  . i never used e. prevendefault. Do i have to add more code in the main code, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope you have written an event in serve code... If not just remove run at server attribute from your button...

I thing you are calling some server event through run at server attribute of your button . that is sending post back which is result in a page reload which making your page to the old color...

To avoid post back page refresh you have to handle it well in server or just remove this run at server attribute from your button(which will result in no server call for your script)..

I hope this solves your problem or helps you to see your problem.

(Sorry for typo. Sent from mobile app).